# Why can't I get a variable from another connection in dolphindb?

Tags: database, session, bigdata, dolphindb

I save the calculation results in a variable in a Java client, but I can't query the variable through dolphindb-gui. My java client and dolphindb-gui connect to the same data node. How can I get the variables in this Java client?

Answer (score 0):

All variables defined in a session is local and invisible to other sessions. Here Java client and dolphindb-gui created two different sessions.